# Ошибка в OPENCART

Tags: opencart, php

> `Warning: require_once(/home/potapovvi/domains/realsila.ru/system/startup.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/potapovvi/domains/realsila.ru/public_html/index.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/potapovvi/domains/realsila.ru/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/potapovvi/domains/realsila.ru/public_html/index.php on line 21`

Файл есть `startup.php`.

В чем может быть дело, подскажите...

Comment: файл точно по этому пути лежит? у PHP есть права на чтение этого файла (в том числе на директории)?

Comment: прав на файл нету например...

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, вы забыли в конфиг-файле прописать `public_html`.

у вас, наверное, путь прописан:

```
/home/potapovvi/domains/realsila.ru/
```

ко всем файлам, а должен быть:

```
/home/potapovvi/domains/realsila.ru/public_html
```

Answer (score 0):

Как написали выше, в данном случае ошибки могут быть в 2 случаях:

1. Неправильные пути в конфигах
2. Нет прав для чтения файлов или катагогов

Посмотрите корневой config.php и admin/config.php на наличие правильных путей. А также посмотрите на права доступа: В файлов они должны быть 644, а в папок - 755

Если права такие, как я написал - ставьте где необходимо 777 и молитесь